# minecraft textures 1 11 item (or subitems) render

Tags: textures, minecraft

I have a problem with textures in Minecraft 1 11
I create Hammer class with subitems:

```java
public Hammer(Hammers hammers){
    this(hammers.name, hammers.size, hammers.material);
}
public Hammer(String name, Size range, Item.ToolMaterial material){
    super(name, material);
    this._range = range;
    this.name = name;
    setUnlocalizedName(name);
    setRegistryName(name);
    setCreativeTab(BookCraft.toolTab);
    hasSubtypes = true;
    this.efficiencyOnProperMaterial /= MathHelper.sqrt(_range.width*_range.height);
}
@Override
public void getSubItems(Item itemIn, CreativeTabs tab, NonNullList<ItemStack> subItems) {
    for (Hammers h : Hammers.values()){
        subItems.add(new ItemStack(new Hammer(h)));
    }
}
public static enum Hammers{
    BUILDER_HAMMER("BuilderHammer", new Size(2,1), ToolMaterial.STONE),
    LIGHT_HAMMER("LightHammer", new Size(2,2), ToolMaterial.IRON),
    MJÖLLNIR("Mjöllnir", new Size(3,2), ToolMaterial.DIAMOND),
    WAR_HAMMER("WarHammer", new Size(2,1), ToolMaterial.DIAMOND),
    LEGENDARY_HAMMER("LegendaryHammer", new Size(5,3), ToolMaterial.DIAMOND);

    public final String name;
    public final Size size;
    public final ToolMaterial material;
    public final float damage;

    Hammers(String name, Size size, ToolMaterial material){
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        this.material = material;
        this.damage = material.getDamageVsEntity();
    }
}
```

This is `ItemInit` class where I register items with texture:

```java
//region Fields
public static Hammer hammes;
//public static Boers boer;
//public static BkAxe axe;
//endregion

//
public static void init(){

    hammes = register(new Hammer(Hammer.Hammers.BUILDER_HAMMER));
    //boer = register(new Boers("boer", new Size(5,3), Item.ToolMaterial.DIAMOND));
    //axe = register(new BkAxe("axe", Item.ToolMaterial.DIAMOND, 7, 7,1000,20));
}

//region Helping Method
private static <T extends Item> T register(T item) {
    GameRegistry.register(item);

    if (item instanceof IBkBase) {
        if (item.getHasSubtypes()){
            item = registerWithSubtypes(item);
        }
        else
            ((IBkBase) item).registerItemModel();
    }

    return item;
}

public static <T extends Item> T registerWithSubtypes(T item){

    NonNullList<ItemStack> items = NonNullList.create();
    item.getSubItems(item, item.getCreativeTab(), items);

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
        Item tempItem = items.get(i).getItem();
            String name = tempItem.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5);
            ModelLoader.setCustomModelResourceLocation(tempItem, i,
                    new ModelResourceLocation(BookCraft.MOD_ID + ":" + name, "inventory"));
        }
    return item;
}
//endregion
```

All the folders are named correctly, search through whole internet, can't find any help

Here are some screenshots:

- Debug info
  [image: Debug info]
- The item is in the Creative Tab and the name is shown
  [image: The item is in the Creative Tab and the name is shown]
- How the item is rendered in the world
  [image: How the item is rendered in the world]
- The `model` folder

  [image: The <code>model</code> folder]

All three *.json have the same text:

```json
{
  "parent": "item/handheld",
  "textures": {
    "layer0": "bk:items/Hammer1"
  }
}
```

Can you suggest any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The resource path "bk:items/Hammer1" does not match the actual path, "bk/models/item/baseHammer"

items
item
items
item

Also, your resource file names need to be all lower case ("hammer1" or "basehammer") as the game will automatically take anything you give it (e.g. "Hammer1") and call `.toLower()` on it, throwing an error if it can't find the file with that exact name (e.g. "Hammer1.json" would not match).

You need to use "bk:items/hammer1" and rename your "item" directory to "items" as well as rename the json file to "hammer1.json" or "builderhammer" (whatever name you actually gave it when you registered it).